# Calculate Period Changes in Unevenly Sampled Times Series in R (or Matlab)

Tags: r, matlab

The heading says it all, I'm trying desperately to figure out a way calculate the period of a time series that is unevenly sampled. I tried creating an evenly sampled time series with NAs for the times where there is no data, but there are just too many NAs for any imputation method to do a reasonable job. The main problem being that the sample times are much further apart than the average period (VERY roughly 0.5), which is only obvious with period-folding applied. Because I'm looking for a small change in period, I can't round the sampling times.

[Time-folded period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox2xg.jpg)

Here is a sample of the data:

```
HJD(time)  Mag    err
2088.91535 18.868 0.078
2090.87535 19.540 0.165
2103.92958 18.704 0.040
2104.94812 19.291 0.098
2106.84596 18.910 0.066
...
4864.56170 18.835 0.061
```

The data set has about 650 rows.

I've spent almost a week googling my problem and nothing has helped yet so any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I have some experience with Matlab too, so if it's possible to do it with Matlab rather than R, I'd be happy with that too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a way to do what you want. The [Nyquist-Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) states that your average sampling frequency needs to be at least twice as high as the frequency of the events you want to capture (roughly speaking).

So if you want to extract information from events with a period of 0.5 [units] you will need a sample every 0.25 [units].

Note that this is a mathematical limitation, not one of R.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. But nevertheless, I can get it to roughly behave with the period-folding (see the image that I didn't add properly the first time).
That rough period of 0.5 days was determined by some method (this data is publicly available on the OGLE website), and I was hoping there was a way to do it in R or Matlab that I could adapt to see how the period changes over time.